# Jasmine test involving a sequence of actions

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am writing test cases in JavaScript and jQuery, the framework is Jasmine and Karma.

```
describe('When a user selects a multiple-response Hotspot response', function () {

    it('Then allow highlighting multiple responses', function (done) {
        utils.clickHotspotElementAtIndex(view, 1, function() {});
        utils.clickHotspotElementAtIndex(view, 0, function() {});
        utils.clickHotspotElementAtIndex(view, 2, function() {});
        setTimeout(function() {
            expect(utils.verifyHotSpotHasBeenHiglightedAtIndex(view, 0)).toBe('true');
            expect(utils.verifyHotSpotHasBeenHiglightedAtIndex(view, 1)).toBe('true');
            expect(utils.verifyHotSpotHasBeenHiglightedAtIndex(view, 2)).toBe('true');
            done();
        }), 2000});
    });
```

What it does is:

1. click on element 1, sync action
2. click on element 0, sync action
3. click on element 2. sync action
4. When the main thread is free, wait for 2 seconds and then
5. expect element 0 has been highlighted
6. expect element 1 has been highlighted
7. expect element 2 has been highlighted

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: @200_success, thanks, this question has nothing to do with jQuery directly. Most of the methods use jQuery in their helper files.

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous functions and hardcoded values can be abstracted. For example:

```
function click(value){
    utils.clickHotspotElementAtIndex(view, value, Function);
}

function tests(value){
    expect(utils.verifyHotSpotHasBeenHiglightedAtIndex(view, value)).toBe('true');
}

function test () {
    [0, 1, 2].map(tests);
}
```

Then the asynchronous code can be modernized via `async/await`:

```
async function sequencer() {
    const clicks = [1, 0, 2].map(click);
    await Promise.all(clicks);
}

function run() {
    beforeEach(sequencer);
    it('Then allow highlighting multiple responses', test);
}
```

And the call can simply be a one-liner:

```
describe('When a user selects a multiple-response Hotspot response', run);
```

**References**

- [Jasmine Tutorial: Asynchronous work](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async)
- [JavaScript loops - how to handle async/await](https://lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795/)